# Binding of grid sub-models using custom editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an editable Kendo UI Grid with a custom editor. Whenever I try to click outside of a textbox in the custom editor (which is when Kendo is setting the value into the grid model) I get a javascript error like the following:

`0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'PercentWeight' of undefined or null reference`

In the debugger, the exception happens in:

```
function anonymous(d,value) {
    d.PercentInfo.PercentWeight=value
}
```

When I hover over `d`, it has all my `IngredientViewModel` properties except for `PercentInfo`, and when I hover over `PercentInfo`, it is `undefined`.

Here is my grid model:

```
public class IngredientViewModel {
    public string EncryptedIngredientId { get; set; }
    public string CasNumber { get; set; }
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }

    [UIHint("PercentWeightEditor")]
    public PercentInfoViewModel PercentInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the `PercentInfoViewModel` model used in `IngredientViewModel`:

```
public class PercentInfoViewModel {
    public decimal? PercentWeight { get; set; }
    public string PercentUnit { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the .cshtml of the grid partial:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IngredientViewModel>(Model)
  .Name("IngredientsGrid")
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).Enabled(true))
  .BindTo(Model)
  .DataSource(ds => ds
      .Ajax()
      .ServerOperation(false)
      .Events(ev => ev.Error("onGridError"))
      .Model(m => {
                 m.Id(p => p.EncryptedIngredientId);
                 m.Field(p => p.EncryptedIngredientId).Editable(false);
                 m.Field(p => p.PercentInfo);
             })
      .Read("IngGrid_Read", "Company")
      .Update("IngGrid_Update", "Company")
      .Create("IngGrid_Create", "Company")
      .Destroy("IngGrid_Destroy", "Company"))
  .ToolBar(tbar => tbar.Create())
  .Columns(c => {
               c.Bound(m => m.CasNumber);
               c.Bound(m => m.IngredientName);
               c.Bound(m => m.PercentInfo).ClientTemplate("#= PercentInfo.PercentWeight # #= PercentInfo.PercentUnit #");
               c.Command(command => {
                             command.Edit();
                             command.Destroy();
                         }).Width(200);
           })
)
```

And here is the PercentWeightEditor .cshtml:

```
@model SupplierPortalWebsite.Models.PercentInfoViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PercentWeight)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PercentUnit)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify the `Model` call of the grid setup to have an empty model as a default value. Below is the new piece of the code:

```
.Model(m => {
             m.Id(p => p.EncryptedIngredientId);
             m.Field(p => p.EncryptedIngredientId).Editable(false);
             m.Field(p => p.PercentInfo)
    /* I added this line --> */     .DefaultValue(new PercentInfoViewModel());
         })
```

This way there is always an empty model to which the custom editor can assign properties, instead of trying to assign to a non-existant object (which is what caused the exception).